# No more handles after limiting amount of generated SWT objects

Tags: java, swt, handle

My application used multiple Hashmaps to store Color and Image objects that were randomly generated whenever a new Key came up (which could be an infinite amount).

To reduce memory usage I am using a Hashfunction to limit the amount of randomly generated Colors and Images to 229.
Weirdly enough when I was storing virtually infinite Colors and Images, the program did run without major issues (except for the leak of course).

Now that I'm trying to re-use a limited set of Objects strangely after a few seconds I keep getting the exception :

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles)
```

The generation of the maps looks something like this:

```
static Map<Integer, Color> color = new Hashtable<>();
    private static final int MAX_COLORS = 229;

    private static void generateColor(String typeName) {
        if (mapping.containsKey(typeName)) {
            return;
        }

        Color c = generateRandomColor(typeName);
        color.put(typeNameHash(typeName), c);
    }

    private static Color generateRandomColor(String typeName) {
        if(color.containsKey(typeNameHash(typeName))){
            return color.get(typeNameHash(typeName));
        }
        int red = random.nextInt(255);
        int green = random.nextInt(255);
        int blue = random.nextInt(255);
        return new Color(Display.getCurrent(), red, green, blue);
    }

    private static int typeNameHash(String typeName){
        return Math.abs(typeName.hashCode())%MAX_COLORS;
    }
```

How is it possible that now, that I should have less objects, I'm running into this kind of exception so fast?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us the full stack trace of the error

Comment: Are you calling `dispose()` on the `Color` instances that you don't keep?

Comment: I just noticed right after posting this question, that I was having a few instances where I was still using the typeName String to get and put some objects into the Maps. One instance is visible right in my example above, in the generateColor function. Weirldy the compiler did not warn me, that I was using Strings as keys, instead of Integers. Because of this it seems like tons of objects were generated.

Comment: And as Baz suggested, check Color, you need to dispose them, Colors, Icons and so on, you need to dispose them when you don't need them anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my issue here was, that I was still using the Strings as keys, instead of calling the hash-function on the strings in some instances.
Since HashMaps take Objects-type for keys the compiler did not warn me about that.

Checking all code parts where I inserted into the Hashmap and making sure the hash-function was used everywhere resolved the issue.